# Manipulating strings c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm working on this assignment for class and I've ran into a problem.

The objective of the program is to have the user to

- Input their first then last name.
- Then the program will ask to in put a nick name.
- Finally the program will output your

  1. first name
  2. nick name all caps in quotes
  3. last name

a more detailed version of the instructions can be found [here](http://syl9.com/194/Assignments/assign9.pdf)

So my problem lies on **how will I manipulate a string to place the nickname in between the first and the last**.

I'm using `cin.getline()` to input the first and last name at the beginning. *I can't seem to find the last name in the string*. Is there a way to read a string/char[] into another string after a certain location in the array.

like if there is a function in some c++ native library that went **(pseudo code)**

```
readFromPoint(array, otherArray, beginPoint, stopPoint);
```

or am i just going to have to build my own loop.

I would like to input my first and last name into one string. Then place them into two separate strings. Then I place (first, nickname, last) into the first and original string.

*I know if I just used two cin statements it could save me a lot of heart ache. (I believe I've heard others call it dangerous)*

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

char Name[46], // the full names leangth - 2
     firstName[16],
     lastName[16],
     nickName[16];
     int numOSpaces;

//void rearrangeName();
int FindSpace(string, int);
int FindNull(string);
int main(){

    cout << "Pleast enter your first then last name...\n";
    cin.getline(Name, 30);
    int ender =  FindSpace(Name, strlen(Name));

    // here we check if you entered the right amount of spaces
    while (numOSpaces > 1 || numOSpaces < 1){
        if (numOSpaces > 1)
        cout << "There are too many spaces only put one space:\n";
        if (numOSpaces < 1)
        cout << "Please separate your first and last name:\n";
        cin.getline(Name, 30);
        ender =  FindSpace(Name, strlen(Name));
    }

    cout << "Hello " << Name <<".\n";

    cout << "\n\nEnter your nickname...\n";\

    cin.getline(nickName, 30);
    cout << "Whats up " <<nickName << "!" << endl << endl;

    // Now we separate the first name and the last name 
    //rearrangeName();
}

// used to tell where user stopped inputting into the string
int FindNull(string find){
    int index = 0;
    do{
        index++;
    }while (isprint(find[index])); // this stops at the null terminator
//      }while (find[index] != '\0');  // as will this 
    return index;
}   

// here we find the first space 
int FindSpace(string mystring, int size){
    int Space;
    int spaceCount = 0;
    for (int index; index < size; index++){
        if (isspace(mystring[index])){
            Space = index;
            spaceCount++;
        }
    }
    numOSpaces = spaceCount;
    return Space;
}

void findName(string fullName, string otherName){

}
```

And I can't use any outside library of course if I want to turn this in that is. Only those native to C++.

Comment: Use `std::string` which is part of the C++ standard library, and then it all becomes easy. Using raw char arrays in C++ is a terrible idea.

Comment: `char Name[46]` et al. Why aren't you use `std::string` for those as well, as you're using it already for your function parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this program which does your job pretty well using `std::string` becuase of it's fancy functions like `find`, `insert`, etc :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string name, nickname;
    getline(cin,name);
    getline(cin,nickname);
    nickname.insert(0," ");     // insert a space before nickname
    int pos = name.find(" ");   // find where space is becuase space separates first & last name
    name.insert(pos, nickname);     // insert nickname at the space, it doesn't trouble because we have a space before nickname
    cout << name;
    return 0;
}
```

Output will be :-

```
Ankit Acharya
Programmer
Ankit Programmer Acharya
```

Hope this will solve your problem pretty well !!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not getting the last name with `cin.getline()` is because it only gets the first string it sees, before the space. Repeat `cin.getline()` twice(or use the following code) to get both the first and last name:

```
std::string firstName, lastName;
std::cin >> firstName >> lastName;
```

This uses only native c++ stuff, included with `<iostream>` and `<cstring>`.
If you need any help with converting the nickname to caps, let me know.

Edit: NEVER use c style strings unless you are forced to; all the tools you need are included in `<string>`.

Comment: That's not what `getline` does.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `std::string`, you'll have a much easier time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void capitalize(std::string& str) {
  for(size_t i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
    str[i] = toupper(str[i]);
  }
}

int main() {
  std::string first_name, last_name, nickname;
  std::cout << "Enter full name: " << std::endl;
  std::cin >> first_name >> last_name;
  std::cout << "Enter nickname: " << std::endl;
  std::cin >> nickname;

  capitalize(nickname);

  std::cout << first_name << " \"" << nickname << "\" " << last_name << std::endl;
}
```

Here's the [ideone](https://ideone.com/6XnNF6) with full name "Hello World" and nickname "nickname".